# NULL & Distinct in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I want to return null values from the customer table and essentialy the equivalent of a select distinct on the Bill code from the bill table.

How would I do this?

Table Customer

```
ID
Name
CustNumber
BILLCODE
```

Table Bill

```
ID
BILLCODE
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
Select Null ID, Null NAME, Null CUSTNUMBER
from CUSTOMER
RIGHT JOIN ID, BILLCODE 
on customer.billcode = bill.billcode
```

I only want 1 record for each billcode in the table.

Comment: Can you give some example table-contents and the resulting desired results? Because right now it's really not clear (to me at least) what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
with billcodes as (select distinct billcode from bill)
select b.billcode, c.id, c.name, c.custnumber
from billcodes b
left outer join customer c on c.billcode=b.billcode
```

alternatively:

```
select b.billcode, c.id, c.name, c.custnumber
from (select distinct billcode from bill) b
left outer join customer c on c.billcode=b.billcode
```

Comment: It looks like the OP tagged the question with Oracle, but its worth noting that this syntax won't work on MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the question is:  how can I return all customers from the customer table with a list of each bill code they have?

If so, you want to use `group by` and `left outer join`:

```
select b.billcode, c.id, c.name, c.custnumber
from customer c left outer join
     bill b
     on c.billcode = b.billcode
group by b.billcode, c.id, c.name, c.custnumber
```